# electron 5.0.0 "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, require

I had initially been using electron stable (4.x.x), and was able to use `require` in both my browser and renderer processes. I upgraded to electron beta (5.0.0) because I needed a newer version of node and encountered this error message in my renderer process, `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

Googling and looking through the electron docs, I found comments saying the error could be caused by setting `webPreferences.nodeIntegration` to false when initializing the `BrowserWindow`; e.g.: `new BrowserWindow({width, height, webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: false}});`. But I was not doing this, so I thought something else must be the issue and continued searching for a resolution.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

For Electron version 12 and above

```
const electron = require("electron");

const { app, BrowserWindow } = electron;

app.on("ready", () => {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    },
  });
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
});
```

Comment: For reference https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17241

Comment: webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    },


these three lines save my life , thanks,

Comment: `contextIsolation: false` fixed it for me
It only worked in older versions without that

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I was missing enableRemoteModule.

Comment: Setting `contextIsolation: false` only works because it disables an important security feature. This is not the approach recommended by the Electron docs. Instead, you should use a preload script to expose whitelisted wrappers for any module your app may need to require. I've explained this further in my answer.

Answer (score 72):

It turns out, `nodeIntegration` was true by default in previous electron versions, but false by default in 5.0.0. Consequently, setting it to true resolved my issue. Not finding this change documented online in comments or on electrons page, I thought I'd make this self-answered SO post to make it easier to find for future people who encounter this issue.

Comment: although when I open DevTool on my electron app (electron v4.1.4), it show the warning that nodeIntegeration is gonna turn false by default on the major releases.

Comment: Well, it helped for me !! Greetings form the future

Answer (score 59):

Like [junvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6951428/junvar) said, `nodeIntegration` is now false by default in 5.0.0.

The [electronjs FAQ](https://electronjs.org/docs/faq#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron) has some sample code on how to set this value.

```
let win = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true
  }
})
win.show()
```

Comment: Any idea why this would still not work for me when I set the flag to true, and even tried to place `const fs = require('fs')` in the renderer.js file as well in the js script file I use?

Comment: having same problem, stuck from 3 Days

Comment: One mistake i made was doing this: 
{ nodeIntegration: true } 
instead of this: 
{ webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true } }

Answer (score 19):

set nodeIntegration to true when creating new browser window.

```
app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me, I was getting upset about Electron

Answer (score 11):

Readers of this post should read the [*Do not enable Node.js Integration for Remote Content*](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content) section from the [*Security, Native Capabilities, and Your Responsibility* Guide](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security) before making a decision.

```
// Bad
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    nodeIntegrationInWorker: true
  }
})
mainWindow.loadURL('https://example.com')

// Good
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    preload: path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'preload.js')
  }
})
mainWindow.loadURL('https://example.com')
```

Comment: How would convert `const electron = require('electron');` this?

Comment: Like this `preload: path.join(app.getAppPath(), 'electron.js')`? electron.js not a file. Actuall location is `node_modules\electron\index.js`. how would you include this as preload?

Comment: you can only preload direct js files, not node modules.

Comment: thank you! i was looking for an alternative than just enable `nodeIntegration`.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming electron 12.0.0

set `contextIsolation: false`

keep below code in main.js

```
new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800, height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
          }
    })
```

Answer (score 10):

For electron 13.0.0

```
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: true,
  contextIsolation: false,
  enableRemoteModule: true
}
```

Comment: where do I put this????

Answer (score 7):

Add `contextIsolation: false` in `webPreferences`

Answer (score 7):

You should **not** set `contextIsolation: false`.

If you do so, as several answers suggest, then certainly your code will no longer fail with "*Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.*"

But that's only because you have disabled the entire security feature!
[Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation) has been on by default since Electron 12 **because it's an important security feature for all Electron applications**. If you set `contextIsolation: false`, that's like removing the lock on the front door of your house to make it possible for your family to get in and out, rather than providing a key to those who are allowed access.

**Instead**, you should set `contextIsolation: true` (the default value) and **use a [preload script](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#preload-scripts) to expose whitelisted wrappers** for any module your app may need to require. You can read more about it at the [Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation) link, and there's a detailed example in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59814127/1657610).

Answer (score 6):

[junvar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6951428/junvar) is right, `nodeIntegration` is false by default in v5.0.0.

It's the last statement in the `Other Changes` section of [Release Notes for v5.0.0](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v5.0.0) and was also mentioned in [this PR](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/16235)