# contextBridge not working with typescript in electron app: Uncaught reference error

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron, ipc

I'm trying to get an electron app running with typescript, where i'm able to structure my code. The most useful starting point in the was the first answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71078436/3735510

However, i'm unable to extend my app, there's no error reported from typescript but during runtime i receive an Uncaught ReferenceError and the call doesn't work.

This is my folder & file structure:

```
├── forge.config.ts
├── node_modules (...)
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   └── loginhandling.ts
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── preload.ts
│   └── renderer.ts
├── tsconfig.json
├── webpack.main.config.ts
├── webpack.plugins.ts
├── webpack.renderer.config.ts
├── webpack.rules.ts
└── yarn.lock
```

This is the forge.config.ts:

```
import { MakerSquirrel } from '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel';
import { MakerZIP } from '@electron-forge/maker-zip';
import { MakerDeb } from '@electron-forge/maker-deb';
import { MakerRpm } from '@electron-forge/maker-rpm';
import { WebpackPlugin } from '@electron-forge/plugin-webpack';

import { mainConfig } from './webpack.main.config';
import { rendererConfig } from './webpack.renderer.config';

const config: ForgeConfig = {
  packagerConfig: {},
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [new MakerSquirrel({}), new MakerZIP({}, ['darwin']), new MakerRpm({}), new MakerDeb({})],
  plugins: [
    new WebpackPlugin({
      mainConfig,
      renderer: {
        config: rendererConfig,
        entryPoints: [
          {
            html: './src/index.html',
            js: './src/renderer.ts',
            name: 'main_window',
            preload: {
              js: './src/preload.ts',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
};

export default config;
```

my package.json:

```
  "name": "someName",
  "productName": "someName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Electron application description",
  "main": ".webpack/main",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": {
    "name": "A Name",
    "email": "someone@this.org"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.4",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.4",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.4",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.4",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.4",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack": "^6.0.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader": "1.7.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "electron": "22.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^7.2.13",
    "node-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "entryPoints": {
    "preload": {
      "js": "./src/preload.ts"
    }
  }
}
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "files": [
    "src/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

auth/index.ts:

```
// api exports functions that make up the frontend api, ie that in
// turn either do IPC calls to main for db communication or use
// allowed nodejs features like file i/o.
// Example `my-feature.ts`: 
// export const fetchX = async (): Promise<X> => { ... }

export default {
    ...loginhandling
}
```

and auth/loginhandling.ts:

```
export const login = async (): Promise<boolean> => { 
    console.log("Triggered login"); 
    return true;
}

export const refresh = async (): Promise<boolean> => { 
    console.log("Triggered refresh"); 
    return true;
}


export const buttonCLicked = async (): Promise<void> => {
    console.log(`button clicked, let's do something!`);
}
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World!</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Hello World!</h1>
    <p>Welcome to your Electron application.</p>
    <p>
      <button class="button" id="loginButton">Login</button>
      <label class="buttonDescription" id="loginButtonDescription">Login details...</label>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my index.ts:

```
// This allows TypeScript to pick up the magic constants that's auto-generated by Forge's Webpack
// plugin that tells the Electron app where to look for the Webpack-bundled app code (depending on
// whether you're running in development or production).
declare const MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY: string;
declare const MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY: string;

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = (): void => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 720,
    width: 1280,
    webPreferences: {
      contextIsolation: false,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY
    },
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_WEBPACK_ENTRY);

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and import them here.
```

the index.d.ts:

```
declare const auth: typeof import("./auth").default;
```

my preload.ts:

```
// https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#preload-scripts

import { contextBridge } from "electron";
import auth from './auth'

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("auth", auth);
```

and the (for me problematic) renderer.ts, currently with two listeners for the same event:

````
 * This file will automatically be loaded by webpack and run in the "renderer" context.
 * To learn more about the differences between the "main" and the "renderer" context in
 * Electron, visit:
 *
 * https://electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model
 *
 * By default, Node.js integration in this file is disabled. When enabling Node.js integration
 * in a renderer process, please be aware of potential security implications. You can read
 * more about security risks here:
 *
 * https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security
 *
 * To enable Node.js integration in this file, open up `main.js` and enable the `nodeIntegration`
 * flag:
 *
 * ```
 *  // Create the browser window.
 *  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
 *    width: 800,
 *    height: 600,
 *    webPreferences: {
 *      nodeIntegration: true
 *    }
 *  });
 * ```
 */

import './index.css';

console.log(' This message is being logged by "renderer.ts", included via webpack');
// auth.login();

// get UI elements and connect
// get button
const loginBttn = <HTMLButtonElement>document.getElementById('loginButton');
// get label
const loginLbl = <HTMLLabelElement>document.getElementById('loginButtonDescription');
loginBttn.addEventListener('click', () => auth.buttonCLicked());

let counter = 0;
loginBttn.addEventListener('click', () => {loginLbl.innerText = `Loging clicked ${++counter} times`});
````

So the event listener changing the label directly does work, the other one just shows as an error:
[image]

**The question:**
How can i get the button click to call the code from auth/loginhandling? To my understanding this is the first step towards other parts of code / long running background tasks that i later want to trigger from buttons in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing following :

```js
loginBttn.addEventListener('click', () => auth.buttonCLicked());
```

With :

```js
loginBttn.addEventListener('click', () => window.auth.buttonCLicked());
```