# How to store local data with electron-store and get these data on renderer process?

Tags: electron

How to store local data with electron-store and get these data on renderer process?

We know that we can use electron-store to store data locally.

But How could we get them and set new data to them?

Answer (score 1):

I am a beginner at Electron and was wondering the same thing. From what I understood of the releases history of Electron which brought several security improvements releases after releases, the main process, the preload.je file and the renderer process have been separated more and more.

So your only option to send and received data between the main and renderer processes is by using ipc messaging. [This great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807459/how-to-use-preload-js-properly-in-electron/59814127#59814127) on Stack Overflow explains it in details and it worked very well for me.

Comment: Thank you! Using ipc must be a safe and a good way to send data from renderer process to main process.But it also make some simple things a little complicated sometimes.