# ipcMain receiving nothing from ipcRenderer

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to do a very simple communication between ipcRenderer and IPCMain but it's not working ! can someone tell me why ?

GALLERY.JS

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
    ipcRenderer.send('test');
});
```

I really don't understand why nothing is printed in my console

GALERYCONTROLLER.JS

```
const { ipcMain} = require('electron');
const userId;
const Axios = require('axios')



ipcMain.on('test', (e) =>{
    console.log('droneDataGallery received')
   })

});
```

gallery.ejs

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/GalleryPage.css"></link>

<div class='galleryPage'>

</div>

<script src="./../assets/js/gallery.js"></script>
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: We'd likely need more context. Is it possible that the message is being sent before the handler is registered?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use the latest version of Electron, you need to expose the ipc messaging system to your HTML (gallery.js) code through the contextBrige object at the preload.js level. [This is very well explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807459/how-to-use-preload-js-properly-in-electron/59814127#59814127) and it worked great for me. Of course, it implies some extra plumbing.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
    ipcRenderer.send(  'test'  ,data you want to send to GALERYCONTROLLER.JS);
});
```

---

```
ipcMain.on('test', (e, data) =>{
// data is array

    console.log(data)
   })

});
```