# Send ipcRenderer variable to vue3 page

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc, vuejs3, ipcrenderer

I have a vue3 app with electron and need to send a variable from the ipcRenderer to my Vue3 page. I cant figure out how to do it especially given vue strips away lots of js. What im trying to do is to save the path of a folder which so far works fine, then display it in the vue3 app either in a span or whatever. I successfully got the value i need to display to the ipcRenderer but cant access it using my vue app.

**Vue3 page**

```
          <q-btn
            id="showpath"
            dark
            flat
            size="xl"
            label="show Path"
            type="submit"
            @click="showpath"
          />
        </div>

export default {
  name: "Settings",
  props: {},
  methods: {
    loader() {
      window.postMessage({
        type: "select-dirs",
      });
    },
    showpath() {
      const testa = window.postMessage({ type: "pathtf"})
      console.log("Vue page says :"+ testa)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

All I get here is "undefined

**Preloader script**

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const settings = require('./settings');

process.once('loaded', () => {
    window.addEventListener('message', evt => {
            if (evt.data.type === 'select-dirs') {
                ipcRenderer.send('select-dirs')

            }

        }),
        window.addEventListener('message', evt => {
            if (evt.data.type === 'pathtf') {
                const pathtf = settings.gettfpath("pathtf")
                console.log(pathtf)
            }

        })
})
```

The console.log in the preload file works and displays the value, but i cant get that value to my vue3 page.

Any tip? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you use electron's contextBridge to expose certain methods (send/receive) to the renderer process.

I do not know what your gettfPath method does but if that variable is available to you in the preloadjs file you should be able to expose it as a variable like so:

```
const {contextBridge} = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electronApi", {
  pathtf: settings.gettfPath()
});
```

With this your path will be exposed to your renderer process as **window.electronApi.pathtf**

Here are two resources you may find helpful:

1. [How to use preload.js properly in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807459/how-to-use-preload-js-properly-in-electron)
2. https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-safely-set-up-an-electron-app-with-vue-and-webpack-556fb491b83 (This one may not be exactly what you are looking for but it has a good explanation / example of how to use ipc with view and electron)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it worked! I get the proper value in my renderer. Just not sure how to display it in vue now. As a prop? Im new to all of this. But gillion thanks!

Comment: Nvm i figured it out! I created a data object and passed it onto v-model and it works perfectly. Thanks